# Is Back-pedalling normal ? chain keeps jumping from higher to lower cog in rear cassette

Tags: chain, shimano, gears, derailleur-rear, drivetrain

I just bought a new bike Marin Pine mountain-1 which has 1 X 11 drivetrain. I want to know is Back peddling normal ? I called my mechanic and he said you should not do back peddling or this will happen.
when I do that it suddenly starts shifting the chain to lower cogs.
I am not sure why ? chain and everything is just 1 week old.

Comment: I had this problem and after a bit of research found people seem to have less problems with some chains  than others.If its a problem, try a KMC chain.  In the end I got mine to acceptable with a couple derailleur adjustments, but I think a few miles on the new chain is what really did it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is typical-ish behavior, especially if your derailleur gets a bit out of adjustment/alignment, the chainline not being quite right, etc.

You shouldn't really be backpedaling significantly, just to move the pedals into the right place (e.g. cornering, starting to ride, etc.). So, this isn't really a problem in real riding. If its happening when you're just moving the pedals (which is about a half turn of the crankset, normally, like getting the pedal up to start riding), then take it back to the shop and get them to check the adjustment of the derailleur.

Comment: Agreed. If back pedaling causes the chain to skip, the index if your rear derailleur may be off. Is there a strange sound when pedaling forward, like it wants to shift but it's not quite there? Either way, an assignment couldn't hurt.

Comment: Shifting is smooth, But when its on the 11th Cog it jumps back to middle when I back pedal

Comment: I would shift to the larges cog, check the assignment of the derailleur, make sure it is aligned, then shift to the smallest and check again. If they are out of line, adjust the derailleur.